# EF Core - Create report table from multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, view, entity-framework-core

I have a report that I need to send to my react frontend that needs to be easily queried and searched. The problem is with the current method we need to pull all the entire database before performing a query due to nested objects and other factors.

To significantly speed up the process I want to create a Report Table/View to query from that stays up to date as the other tables change.

Here is a small example of the models:

```
public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public ItemType Type { get; set; }

        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class ItemType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemReport
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }

        public ItemReport(Item item)
        { 
            Name = item.Name;
            Description = item.Description;
            Type = item.Type.Name;
            Customer = item.Order.Customer.Name;

        }
    }
```

ItemReport is the model I use to send to the frontend.
I've read a fair amount on Keyless Entities and Views, but am in need of a little guidance on putting all the pieces together.

Currently we would pull all Items and required fields like Name from customer and turn it into an IEnumerable list of ItemReport to then be filtered/sorted or searched.

As a side note, there may be other solutions than the on I'm posting for that I would be open to as well.

I've looked into this quite a bit, but I don't think I'm finding the right solutions as an example when reading on Views they mention how they cannot be inserted into or updated with EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple projection. Passing `item` in Constructor is not right way, because EF Core cannot look into compiled method body.

```cs
var query = context.Items
    .Select(item => new ItemReport
    {
        Name = item.Name;
        Description = item.Description;
        Type = item.Type.Name;
        Customer = item.Order.Customer.Name;
    });
```